# Ceph Recovery Software Not Working ON Newest Version

Tags: ceph, proxmox

Ok so I had a bunch of issues on my ceph cluster, and long story short, We need to recover the images from it another way...

So I had a look around, and after searching a bit found this: https://gitlab.lbader.de/kryptur/ceph-recovery/tree/master
Which looks fantastic, But does not work. I spoke to the dev and asked if we can get it working on the newest version of ceph, but have not heard back yet...

Does anyone have a suggestion for how we can get the script working, I don't code in Bash, so I have no idea what's going on there...
I'd even be willing to pay for a solution that works. Getting a bit desperate!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not really an answer but just pointer to information, that might help you to recover your stuff. This problem is very delicate and can not be answered in one response.

The tools you mention are also referenced in the book [Mastering Ceph 2nd Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/virtualization-and-cloud/mastering-ceph-second-edition). Is it possible you are using BlueStore for OSDs? In that case you can't simply mount the OSDs. The book dives into how to recover RBD images from BlueStore OSDs. Of course I can't reproduce the information from the book here. It is just a pointer of information.

Additionally I would strongly suggest to reach out to the Ceph community on their [user mailing list](https://lists.ceph.io/postorius/lists/ceph-users.ceph.io/). It also has a web frontend. Maybe there are other means to get your data recovered.

And one more: As you wrote you are not familiar with bash scripting. So you should most probably find someone with Linux insight to help you with your problem.